# Setting system-wide environment in Makefile

Tags: makefile, installation, environment, shtool

Is there some platform-independent way to setup a system-wide environment from the Makefile? Specifically, I need to add a path to the CLASSPATH variable during install, to have other programs see the installed jars.

I know that sometimes I can put script into /etc/profile.d/, or modify /etc/environment or perhaps use setx.exe on Windows (which needs to be installed, and this is not good).

I'm thinking about some shtool-style solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In GNU make, just set the variable in the makefile, and then `export` it.

```
export ENV_VAR += some/more/stuff
```

See [Communicating Variables to a Sub-make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion) for precise details of `export`.

(I suspect though you may be asking whether to use forward-slashes and colons, or back-slashes and semi-colons in your path definition. That's another question(answer).)